# NoWrap on jQuery Mobile Text to Show in Multiple Lines

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile for hosting the css and js files. In one of my views I have a text which does not wrap. In chrome I see the style and it says "nowrap". How can I override it.  I cannot change the css since it is hosted on the jQuery website. Of course I can download the css and js and change that but currently I don't want to do it.

[image]

Comment: Just add your custom CSS `.ui-listview>li p { overflow: visible; }`

Comment: I used white-space:normal; and it worked. Thanks!